# Screen recording phone and Discord calls with sound

Tags: screencast, call-recording, discord

How can I screen-record phone or Discord calls with sound? I tried the in-built screen recorder and the set of task-related apps but unfortunately the first does not work and the second type either screen records soundlessly or does not screen record at all when it comes to calls.

How can I manage to circumvent the whole block?
Does it relate only to Android or every system?

I want to record on the device itself and not with another device.

Answer (score 1):

- You can simply have another device recording everything. Anything you can hear or see can be recorded.
- You can run Android in a VM (e.g. on your PC) and record everything again - VirtualBox will do it happily.
- There are Android VMs in the Google Play Store. Whatever restrictions apps have won't affect the Android VM - thus you can possibly record everything.
- Many Android phones have wireless casting or even an HDMI output - this will probably facilitate in recording everything quite easily.
- Discord has a PC version. No recording limitations whatsoever then AFAIK. You can use OBS or anything similar.